# Create and save composer with Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

With QGIS 2.8 I need to create some composers based on a template, and save them using Python.

I've found how to load a template in a composition, but I can't find how to save this composition in the list of composers, nor how to create a QgsComposerView.

Do you know how to do so, or tell me where to look?

Comment: is there a solution for this? looking for the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new composer like :

```
# it return a QgsComposerView
compo = iface.createNewComposer(title=u"My compo")
# template must be a QDomDocument
compo.composition().loadFromTemplate(template)
# you can then print your brand new composer
iface.activeComposers()
```